# output from the lightgbm.cv method

Tags: python-3.x, lightgbm

I am trying to use the lightbgm CV method from lightbgm for a multi classification problem

```
import lightgbm as lgb

dftrainLGB = lgb.Dataset(data = X_train, label = y_train)

params = {'objective': 'multiclass', 'num_class' : 3, 'random_state': 42}

cv_results = lgb.cv(
        params,
        dftrainLGB,
        num_boost_round=100,
        nfold=10,
        metrics='multi_logloss',
        early_stopping_rounds=10,
        verbose_eval=20
        )
```

How to use the best parameters from cv_results to train my model? Indeed :

```
model = lgb.train(params, dftrainLGB)
```

would not use cv_results

Answer (score -1):

cv_results will give you the best number of iteration. In R, this is cv_results$$best_iter. In the lgb.train function, you must specify this, nrounds = cv_results$best_iter. Check the names for python, hope this helps.